# How to poll another server periodically from a node.js server?

Tags: node.js, polling

I have a node.js server **A** with mongodb for database. 
There is another remote server **B** (doesn't need to be node based) which exposes a HTTP/GET API '/status' and returns either 'FREE' or 'BUSY' as the response.

When a user hits a particular API endpoint in server **A**(say POST /test), I wish to start polling server **B**'s status API every minute, until server **B** returns 'FREE' as the response. The user doesn't need to wait till the server **B** returns a 'FREE' response (polling B is a background job in server A). Once the server **A** gets a 'FREE' response from **B**, it shall send out an email to the user.

How can this be achieved in server **A**, keeping in mind that the number of concurrent users can go large ?

Comment: Polling server B will just be a background process or do you need the user gets aware of the return values FREE or BUSY? Anyway, check https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback for a basic implementation of a get request in node.js.

Comment: @timo: Polling server B will just be a background process. Once the server B returns FREE, i shall do some task like sending an email.

Comment: please, check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use Agenda. https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda
With agenda you can create recurring schedules under which you can schedule anything pretty flexible.

I suggest you use request module to make HTTP get/post requests. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: Thanks for suggesting agenda. It seems to solve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Going from the example in node.js docs I'd go with something like the code here. I tested and it works. BTW, I'm assuming here that the api response is something like `{"status":"BUSY"}` & `{"status":"FREE"}`

```
const http = require('http');

const poll = {
    pollB: function() {
        http.get('http://serverB/status', (res) => {
            const { statusCode } = res;

            let error;
            if (statusCode !== 200) {
                error = new Error(`Request Failed.\n` +
                    `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
            }

            if (error) {
                console.error(error.message);
                res.resume();
            } else {
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                let rawData = '';
                res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
                res.on('end', () => {
                    try {
                        const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);

                        // The important logic comes here
                        if (parsedData.status === 'BUSY') {
                            setTimeout(poll.pollB, 10000); // request again in 10 secs
                        } else {
                            // Call the background process you need to
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error(e.message);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
        });
    }
}

poll.pollB();
```

You probably want to play with this script and get rid of unnecessary code for you, but that's homework ;)

**Update:**

For coping with a lot of concurrency in node.js I'd recommend to implement a cluster or use a framework. Here are some links to start researching about the subject:

[How to fully utilise server capacity for Node.js Web Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366461/how-to-fully-utilise-server-capacity-for-node-js-web-apps)

[How to Create a Node.js Cluster for Speeding Up Your Apps](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-a-node-js-cluster-for-speeding-up-your-apps/)

[Node.js v7.10.0 Documentation :: cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

[ActionHero.js :: Fantastic node.js framework for implementing an API, background tasks, cluster using http, sockets, websockets](https://www.actionherojs.com/)

Comment: Your code answers the first part of my question, `How can this be achieved in server A` . I would also like to know if this simple setTimeout based implementation is enough to satisfy the second part of my question `keeping in mind that the number of concurrent users can go large`?

Comment: If this process has to run for every single request you just need to implement a cluster or a similar solution to escalate in case there is too much demand on your server. That's a quite complex task and I'd recommend a search for a solution online. I'll update the answer with a few links.

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like request, superagent, or restify-clients to call server B. I would recommend you avoid polling and instead use a webhook when calling B (assuming you are also authoring B). If you can't change B, then setTimeout can be used to schedule subsequent calls on a 1 second interval.